# Duplicate record issue when using Entity Framework and concurrent connections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
var DoesNotExist = this.db.Regions.Where(!m.Reports.Any(r => r.ReportId == m.ReportId)).ToList();

foreach (var item in DoesNotExist)
                        {
                            Report rpt = new Report { ReportId = item.ReportId, ReportDate = endDate };
                            this.db.Reports.AddObject(rpt);

                            foreach (var Point in this.db.RegionalData.Where(s => s.ReportId == item.ReportId && s.ReportDate == lastendDate))
                            {
                                if (this.db.RegionalData.Where(d => d.ReportId == Point.ReportId).Count() == 0)
                                {
                                    StateData sd = new StateData
                                    {
                                        ReportDate = endDate,
                                        ReportId = Point.ReportId,
                                        Female = Point.Female,
                                        Male = Point.Male,
                                        Total = Point.Total,
                                       };
                                    this.db.RegionalData.AddObject(sd);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (DoesNotExist.Count() != 0)
                        {
                            this.db.SaveChanges();
                        }
```

I have the above code that checks if reports for a Region do not exist, and if they do not exist i insert them.

The problem i'm having is that if two users trigger the execution of this code a few seconds apart, two reports for the same region are created which creates duplicates since a region can only have one report.

How best can i resolve this?

I tried calling putting 
`if (missingReportData.Count() != 0)
                            {
                                this.db.SaveChanges();
                            }`

immediately after `this.db.Reports.AddObject(rpt);` but still the issue persisted.

Comment: Is it a Web or Client application? You could use a `lock`. Also remember that you should not keep your context open, just instantiate and dispose it as soon as you are done with it.

Comment: its an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: How to handle concurrency in EF: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592904.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by adding a unique index that prevents you from inserting two reports for the same region. Without seeing your model it's hard to say if it should be the primary key or not.

This way database server will throw an exception if there is already a report for that region. Then you can handle that exception by switching to an update or show an error to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a transaction but you need to update EF4 to EF6.